# Is there a way to always show running word count in the vim ruler?

Tags: vim

I can get the current document word count in vim, with the keyboard combo:

```
g ctrl-g
```

Is there a way to get a running word count in the vim ruler?

Answer (score 3):

If you would like the word count in the statusline (similar to ruler, only customizable) for the entire document, you might want to check some of the answers in [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114431/fast-word-count-function-in-vim).

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe that something as common and simple as showing a word-count is so non-trivial in vim...

Comment: @JamieBullock - It is relatively non trivial. Period. Only in most cases we don't see the underlining code. The algorithm is trivial, count the words, eh, but what is a word, really?